# Average Word value in a sentence based on ASCII value for each letter

Tags: java

I wanted to calculate Average of each word based on ASCII value 
For EX: Hello , H= 72 , e= 101 , l= 108 , l = 108 , o = 111
Summing it up would give 500 and then calculate average based on number of letters i.e 500/5 =100 Therefore Avg of Hello = 100 , in the same way for " World " and so on .
Finally calculate the Average value of all the words , sum it up and display as Final Average of whole Sentence
This is the code i created but it gives an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
   import java.util.*;
   import java.lang.*;
   import java.io.*;
    class Word
    {
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {

    String str="Hello World";
    int average1=0;
    int j=0;
    int[] average=new int[20];
    String[] s=str.split(" "); //Splitting into each word
    for(String s1 : s)
    {
    char[] c=s1.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        average[i]=(int)c[i]; //Average ASCII based value for each word
    }
    while(average[j]!=0)
    {
    average1=average[j]/s1.length(); //Sum up average of each Word and average of who words is calculated 
    System.out.print(average1); 
    j++;
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

If someone could help me with a good logic it would be appreciative.

Comment: *"[...] i.e 500/5 =100 Therefore Avg of Hello = 500"* - I don't understand your interpretation of *"average"*.

Comment: **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** `->` you are looping _str.length()_ which is equal to 55 instead of using this use _c.length_ in your for loop, also there are lots of problems in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your clue & for the latter part , am still into novice stages in learning java and challenging myself to solve some new things but somethings are quite complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to achieve that is doing something like this:

```
public class WordAverage{
   public static void main (String[] args) {

       String str="Hello World"; 
       double average=0; // you need only one double variable, why double -> because of the division later 
        // note that if you don't want the decimal you can change it to int
        for(char c : str.toCharArray()){ // cycle through every char in the String
            if(c!=' '){ // if it is not a space
               average += (int)c; // sum its value
            }
        }

       average /= str.replace(" ", "").length(); // then divide the average value by the String length after removing the spaces (if any)
        System.out.println(average);
    }
  }
```

**Test**

```
Hello World     -> 102.0
How Are You?    -> 96.2
Fine Thank You! -> 95.23
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code out. This is a bit simpler than yours. It averages every word, then averages the averages.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class Word
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        String str="Hello World";

        String[] s = str.split(" ");
        int[] average = new int[s.length];
        for(int i = 0; i<s.length; i++) {
                int wordAverage = 0;
                System.out.println(s[i]);
                for(int j=0;j<s[i].length(); j++) {
                        wordAverage += (int)s[i].charAt(j); //Average ASCII based value for each word
                }
                average[i] = wordAverage/s[i].length();
                System.out.println(average[i]);
        }
        int finalAverage = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<average.length; i++)
                finalAverage += average[i];
        finalAverage/=average.length;
        System.out.println(finalAverage);
    }
}
```